# Efficient way to find out which branches and/or commits point to an object?

Tags: git

Given a [git object](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), is there a way to traverse upwards to find all commits and/or branches which point to it, or are they only linked in one direction? E.g.:

```
BLOB1 ----
          \
BLOB2 ----- C1 ---- C2 ---- B1
      \
       ---- C3 ---- B2
```

Starting from `B1`, can I traverse down to `BLOB2`, and then traverse back up to locate `B2` (and any other branches which point to the same blob)? Or do I have to inspect all branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only "traverse down" the relationship graph as you describe it, but not "back up", because all object relations in this context are *unidirectional associations* (i.e. a commit knows only its parents, but not its children; a tree knows its blobs but blobs don't know what trees reference them).

The only way to find out which commits include a specific blob is thus to traverse the complete history graph (the entry points are your named refs, i.e. branches and tags).

This is the same thing that `git gc` does to determine orphaned objects to be garbage-collected.

Comment: Thanks, confirmed what I suspected.